# TablewView example in Beginning iPhone book

Tags: iphone, memory-management

This is probably a dumb question, but in the introduction to TableViews, the author has a property of NSArray *listData to fill the table with dummy data.  In the viewDidLoad, he basically does this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects@"1", @"2", @"3", more stuff, nil];
self.listData = array;
[array release];
...
}
```

Why does he create another array and set it to the property as opposed to doing something like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
listData = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects@"1", @"2", @"3", more stuff, nil]autorelease];
```

Is it to manage memory better by using alloc/init vs the autorelease pool?  Or is the second way just not going to work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong and is likely to crash.  In his code, he calls `alloc`, meaning the retain count is 1.  He then assigns it to a property.  I'm assuming this property is declared to be `retain`, in which case the retain count would go up to 2.  He then called `release`, which drops the retain count back to 1.

In your code, you call `alloc`, meaning the retain count is 1, then you call `autorelease`, which means that the retain count will drop to 0 and the object's memory will be deallocated soon.  You assign the object to an instance variable - not a retained property like he does - so you won't increase the retain count any more.  This means that you'll be left with a dangling pointer to memory that could be overwritten with anything else at any time.  When you try to access `listData`, you'll crash because it is likely to have been overwritten.

Please read [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) if you do not understand what is happening here.

Having said that, the core of your question is valid.  There's nothing stopping him from doing the same as you, except assigning to a retained property instead of an instance variable.

Comment: I'm still getting used to "self."  In my code snippet, I meant to refer to the listData property that was declared with retain as well.  Do I have to have self in this case to refer to that property?  Otherwise it is an ivar only in scope of that method?  (Sorry, some of the OOAD, props, ivars are still sinking in). Thx.

Comment: When you declare and synthesise a property, an instance variable is created with the same name, along with a getter and a setter.  If the property is declared to `retain`, then when you assign an object to the property, the synthesised setter will send that object a `retain` message.  If you don't use `self.` then you aren't assigning to the property, you're bypassing the setter and assigning directly to the instance variable, so the object's retain count won't increase.

Comment: It's not really about scope.  An instance variable is a variable that is part of an object (an object is merely an *instance* of a class).  Scope is only relevant because an autoreleased object with a retain count of 0 is only guaranteed to not be deallocated in the current scope (more or less).